# APPIUM: Open expo with URL argument without DeepLinking

Tags: expo, appium, wdio

In my current project we open Expo through safari using DeepLink.
I was wondering if it is possible to open Expo and directly pass URL argument, skipping safari step.
Something Like this

```
await driver.execute('mobile: launchApp', {bundleId: 'host.exp.Exponent','--URL': EXPO_REMOTE_URL} )
```

I also tried to access the "Enter URL manually" to input URL using appium but it seems to be unaccessible

[image]